# jQuery click() still activates anchor, even though click function returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I've got a very basic jQuery tab setup. Everything worked fine, but I needed a hash in the URL to dictate the active tab, so I added a condition to check for the hash. Now when the page loads, it's actually activating the anchor and shifting the page down. Why isn't the "return false;" working?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $(".tabs a").click(function() {
    $(".tabs a").removeClass("active");
    $(".tabs a").addClass("button secondary");
    $(this).attr("class","button active");
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $(href).parent().find("> .active").removeClass("active");
    $(href).addClass("active");
    return false;
  });
  if(window.location.hash) {
    $(".tabs a[href$='"+window.location.hash+"']").click();
  } else {
    $(".tabs a:eq(0)").click(); //default to first tab
  }
});
```

**

## Here are some updates:

**

If I simply enter the actual hash value instead of pull it from window.location.hash, it works perfectly.

```
$(".tabs a[href$='#Contact2']").click();
```

Clicking the different tabs DOES NOT shift the page, only when the page loads and automatically clicks the tab based on the hash value.

If I place a conditional and then automatically click without using a a variable within the jquery selector, it works fine, assuming the location hash does not match the hash I'm clicking (strange, I know...)

```
if(window.location.hash === "#Contact2") {
  $(".tabs a[href$='#Contact4']").triggerHandler("click");
} else {
  $(".tabs a:eq(0)").click(); //default to first tab
}
```

This really doesn't make much sense to me. It seems that the only issue is using the window.location.hash within the jquery selector...

Comment: You can just do `$(".tabs a").click(` instead of doing the `click()` inside the `each()` by the way

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've removed it (and made some other optimizations)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe also this code should make your work:

```
 $(".tabs a").click(function(){
            // your code 
            return false;
 });
```

The other way is:

```
$(".tabs a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `preventDefault()` instead.  Don't forget the `e` inside `.click(function(e)`.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $(".tabs a").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".tabs a").removeClass("button secondary active");
      $(".tabs a").addClass("button secondary");
      $(this).attr("class","button active");
      var href = $(this).attr("href");
      $(href).parent().find("> .active").removeClass("active");
      $(href).addClass("active");
    });
  });
  if(window.location.hash) {
    $(".tabs a[href$='"+window.location.hash+"']").click();
  } else {
    $(".tabs a:eq(0)").click(); //default to first tab
  }
});
```

And then chaining some things together...

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $(".tabs a").each(function() {
     $(this).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".tabs a").removeClass("button secondary active").addClass("button secondary");
      $(this).attr("class","button active");
      var href = $(this).attr("href");
      $(href).parent().find("> .active").removeClass("active")
      $(href).addClass("active");
    });
  });
  if(window.location.hash) {
    $(".tabs a[href$='"+window.location.hash+"']").click();
  } else {
    $(".tabs a:eq(0)").click(); //default to first tab
  }
});
```

I'm not sure what you're doing here...

```
      $(".tabs a").removeClass("button secondary active")
      $(".tabs a").addClass("button secondary");
```

The second line instantly adds two classes you removed with the first line.

Comment: Yes, the code could definitely use a bit of optimization. It's just something I grabbed from an example somewhere. The e.preventDefault(), unfortunately, does is not preventing the anchor from scrolling down to the div with the same ID. And you are entirely correct about the removeClass/addClass redundancy. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` does nothing in a jQuery handler, _unless for some reason an exception is thrown before the `return false` line_.

Comment: Which is peculiar, because it DOES prevent the default anchor function from occurring when I manually click, but not when I'm automatically clicking based on the hashed value. I'm getting no errors in my console log.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is very recursive. Try to avoid running a collection across a collection.

Here are a few snippets from a jQuery 1.7+ implementation that might do what you need.

... initialization

```
$(body).on("click", ".tabs a", { }, _selectTab);
```

... some function

```
_selectTab : function(event) {
    $(".tabs a").removeClass(selected); // clear all matches.
    $(event.currentTarget).addClass(selected); // something like that.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.click()` use [`.triggerHandler("click")`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/)

Also, your click handler needs an `e` event parameter and you need to call [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) instead of the old-school `return false`.

Lastly, instead of `if(window.location.hash)` use `if(window.location.hash.length > 0)`

Comment: .triggerHandler as well as e.preventDefault gives me the same issue. They work when I manually click or automatically click the the first tab, but the page still shifts when automatically clicking a tab based on the hash value.

Comment: No dice. The click is performing as expected, however the page is still shifting to the div when it matches the current window.location.hash. Thanks anyway, though.

Answer (score 0):

Pure Javascript Solution to stop all hash default click

`var a_tag = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < a_tag.length; i++) {
        a_tag[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            var lastChar = this.href.substr(this.href.length - 1);
            if (lastChar == "#") {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }, false);
    }`